# Gurobi best bound in the reporting

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I don't understand the output from a MIP run in Gurobi: I set MipGap = 0.005 and TimeLimit = 20.

[image]
See the first red box; after 20s, the gap is 0.0062, greater than MIPGap, and the solver stops because of the TimeLimit.

However, then it reports a gap of 0.004831 (second red box), smaller than the MIPGap. So, why it didn't stop before? Maybe it found the best solution just before reaching the TimeLimit, but it is not the case. Even if I reduce the TimeLimit to 15s I get exactly the same gaps.

What is this 2.060000e+02 reported as best bound (it never appears in the BestBd column, but it appears in the Current node section already at time 10).

So, I understand how the 0.0062 is calculated from here (http://www.gurobi.com/resources/getting-started/mip-basics) but I don't understand how to interpret the 0.004831 value. Which one should I report to represent the quality of the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Trust the solution (and by that i mean the attributes which are returned or can be read in general; not the prints to console)! The table is just some shortened representation and effects like these (ordering, time-sync) are not uncommon (print machinery is heavy; threads, timer-precision...) (i would also be not surprised to see that there is no exact *shut-down-everything* at second x; but some tolerance in sub-secs to clean up internal-data and why not take a better result if that clean-up gives one)

Comment: What Gurobi version are you using?

Comment: @Sonja Mars: Still 6.0.4 :-(   I should find time to upgrade...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, double-check that you set MIPGap correctly, by leaving TimeLimit at defaults and solving again.  If so, then it looks like a race condition: the last log line occurs at node 2342, and there was a small amount of progress until stopping at node 2360.  This is normal with a time limit, which potentially creates non-determinism.